# How do I use Core Motion and gyroscope in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, gyroscope, core-motion

I've been searching some information about Core motion and gyroscope, and I haven't yet found any proper answer.

I'm working with Xcode 5

My question:

How can I make an image (or in this case a player) to go left or right by tilting the iPhone, just like the character in the game called "Doodle Jump"?

I've already got it jumping, but I can't make it move left or right by tilting the iPhone.
I also have a developer account, and I've tried it with an actual device.

Any sort of help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You will save some downvotes and get some good answers if you post the code that you have tried.

Comment: xcode neither has Core Motion nor a gyroscope. it is just an IDE.

Comment: @vefthym I disagree, I think he's very clear in his title: "How do I use Core Motion and gyroscope". His question is kinda specific though. So in fact, thank god he didn't paste in what he already has. Or else it would be very unuseful for future readers

Comment: I think you mean SDK 7 by xcode 5 Kaspersson

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new Spritekit project:

[image]

2.Add the Core Motion Framework

[image]

3.Add this code in the 'touchesBegan' method of you MyScene.m file:

> sprite.size=CGSizeMake(20, 20);

4.Add this code in the 'update' method of you MyScene.m file:

```
CMMotionManager* _motionManager;
 -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
     if (_motionManager==nil) {
         _motionManager=[[CMMotionManager alloc]init];
         _motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval=0.25;
         [_motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
     }
     SKSpriteNode *sprite;
     for (int i=0; i<self.children.count;i++) {
        sprite=[self.children objectAtIndex:i];
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x * _motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch*10, sprite.position.y);
     }
}
```

You can find a more detailed version [here](http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.com/2014/04/howto-use-device-motion-sensors-to.html).

Here's a small [video](http://youtu.be/EZGBCia9XJM) with the result of this code

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there's one problem. My game is in Single View Application. I cant use spritekit game's commands because of that. Any ideas how this could be made in single view application?

Comment: CMMotionManager is not part of SpriteKit. You can use it also for UIViews. Instead of repositioning the SKSpriteNode you have to adjust the position of your UIView